# How can I create a function in python that counts the coincidences between two lists?

Tags: python

If in the first list an element is repeated, and in the second list this element also appears, this might be counted as 1 coincidence

Example:

```
>>> comptaCoincidencies(['verd', 'groc', 'blau', 'vermell'], ['marro', 'blau', 'blanc', 'negre']) 
0 
>>> comptaCoincidencies(['verd', 'groc', 'blau', 'vermell'], ['blanc', 'negre', 'verd', 'groc']) 
2
>>> comptaCoincidencies(['verd', 'groc', 'blau', 'vermell'], ['vermell', 'blau', 'groc', 'verd']) 
4
>>> comptaCoincidencies(['verd', 'verd', 'verd', 'verd'], ['vermell', 'blau', 'groc', 'verd']) 
1
```

I have done this:

```
def comptaCoincidencies(l1, l2):
    """
    Donades dues llistes, retorna el nombre d'elements coincidents entre le llistes
    >>> comptaCoincidencies(["verd", "verd"], ["blau", "blau"])
    0
    >>> comptaCoincidencies(["verd", "vermell"], ["verd", "blau"])
    1
    >>> comptaCoincidencies(["verd", "blau"], ["blau", "verd"])
    2
    """
    comptador = 0
    for i in range(0, len(l1)):
        if l1[i] in l2:
            comptador = comptador + 1
    return comptador
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a set of the duplicated elements

```
set(filter(set(lst1).__contains__, lst2))
```

and adding the len will calculate its length so the count of the duplicate elements

```
len(set(filter(set(lst1).__contains__, lst2)))
```

Update based on `@Willem Van Onsem` comment

```
set(lst1) & set(lst2)
```

Comment: What is wrong with `set(lst1) & set(lst2)`. Tat being said, do not answer questions that show zero effort...

Comment: You're right bro 0 effort, but I think it's his first question maybe first steps in programming so why not help him and next time he will ask a well formed question with efforts included

Comment: because next time, people can make a *new* account, and pretend it is again the first time. Furthermore it gives the false impression that we answer 0-effort questions, and thus more 0-effort questions will be asked.

Comment: Now i fixed it, sorry i am new user and don't know much about how stackoverflow works...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're definitely right, now our friend knew how it works and he show us his effort, and I like the notes in your bio

Comment: @taoufikA: well I did not dv the Q (I only posted a link to the dv page) :-), honestly :).